# CSS float, clear a "row" of floating elements

Tags: css-float, css

I want to create a "scorecard" grid to output some data. If the data in each div.item is all the same height, then a simple float left on each div.item gives a nice even layout which scales up and down nicely depending on browser size.

If the data however is variable, a different number of lines in each div, then the way elements float gives an uneven and messy output. See code sample below. If you create a page with the below, resize the browser to about 800px wide so that box 1, 2, and 3 create a "row" on top, followed by 4, 5 and 6. How do I get 7 to drop down to the next line so it creates a row along with 8 and 9?

Obviously if you resize the browser so that 4 divs appear in each row, number 9 is the element I want to break down below 5.  Is there something obvious I am missing or do I need to use some Javascript to achieve this?

```css
div.item{
  float:left;
  width:220px;
  background-color:#DBDBDB;
  margin:8px;
}

h1, p{
  padding:4px;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class='item'>
  <h1>1</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class='item'>
  <h1>2</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class='item'>
  <h1>3</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Change `"float: left;"` to `"display: inline-block;` `vertical-align: top;"`

and it will work the way you want.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yK9eY/2/

```css
div.item {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    width:220px;
    background-color:#DBDBDB;
    margin:8px;
    vertical-align: top;
    zoom: 1; 
}

h1, p {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='item'>
  <h1>1</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class='item'>
  <h1>2</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class='item'>
  <h1>3</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class='item'>
  <h1>4</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class='item'>
  <h1>5</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
  <p>More Content</p>
</div>

<div class='item'>
  <h1>6</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class='item'>
  <h1>7</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class='item'>
  <h1>8</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class='item'>
  <h1>9</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, works well. Sometimes we are forced to use pages with quirks mode, so here's a fix for IE7 Standards and all IE quirks mode:
 "zoom:1;
 *display:inline;
 vertical-align:top;"

Comment: Updated example with fix for future generations. :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all divs with a container and give `.container { overflow: hidden; }` or `.container { overflow: auto }` to it. 
The second way is wrap all divs with a container and put another div to bottom of all divs and give  a class name such example"clear" and style it `.clear { clear: both }`

Comment: Doesn't work, changing the overflow creates one column of divs and wraping them all and placing a clearing div at the bottom makes no difference to the defualt behaviour.