# Webpage images doesn't stay straight

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm facing a problem but stuck on this i am creating a page which has five images in it. Page has two `stylesheets` `normalize,main`.`main` is my custom stylesheet. And here is sample of page.

[image: Image 1]

I want to make this page responsive but when i resize the browser with small width the navigation bar and images doesn't stay straight it's show preview like this. These all images are position through unordered list Download Page [Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1H5fdK2PJAnVGdqdTN5YTYtMWc)

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS float, clear a "row" of floating elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947886/css-float-clear-a-row-of-floating-elements)

Comment: Follow advice in dup. link and then also change to this `width:44%;` in your `#gallary li` rule.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your css and found the possible cause of the problem. It has to do with the `float:left` property your using. What happens when you use it is that the browser tries to stack everything to the left of your screen. In your case, since one of the list items was longer(height wise) than the usual ones it could not find space to put it. In cases like that, its much better to use the flexbox. here is how

```
   #gallary{
   display: inline-flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   list-style-type: none;
   }
   #gallary li{
   width:45%;
   margin:2.5%;
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
   color:#bdc3c7;
   }
```

By contrast, this code tries to arrange the items in a row and in the case where there is no space available, it warps around and puts it below it. `display: inline-flex;` creates the flex box and `flex-wrap: wrap;` tells it to warp. note that i have removed the `float:left`